# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /opt/lampp/htdocs//app/engine.class.php on line 34

Tags: php

I have this error when I try to execute my php code:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&' in /opt/lampp/htdocs//app/engine.class.php on line 34

```
private function setMatches($doc)
{
    $strMatches = array();
    $positions = $this->getPositions($doc);

    foreach ($positions as $v)
    {
        $start = $v;
        $end = 1;
        $v++;
        while ($end !== 0)
        {
            if (preg_match("/^<div/", &$doc[$v]))
                $end++;
            else if (preg_match("/^<\/div/", &$doc[$v]))
                $end--;
            $v++;
        }
        $end = $v - 1;
        $strMatches[] = substr($doc, $start, $end - $start);
    }
    print_r($strMatches);
}
```

So, here I try to get the address of the character, to pass it in the preg match function as a string.
i dont get it, any idea?

Comment: Php is similar, but different, to C. Uset substr ($doc, $v) to do your matches.

Comment: Also consider using [`DOM`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call time pass by reference has been removed in PHP. So I'm guessing where you're pre-pending `&` to `$doc` generates a syntax error. Remove those `&`s.